# SQL query to output all results but only one specific value from a list without duplicating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of people and a table of client types (linked by a 3rd table called client type details) which these people are linked to. Client types could be 'Friend', 'Enemy', 'Alien', or 'Monster'. Some people can have more than one of these and some people have none.

What I'm really trying to get is an output something like:

```
ID  | Name | Friend  | Enemy   | Alien   | Monster |
35  | John | Friend  | -blank- | -blank- | Monster |
42  | Eric | -blank- | -blank- | -blank- | -blank- |
```

So John is both a Friend and a Monster whereas Eric isn't any. With the query I have tried creating (just with a column for the Friends in the first instant) I am getting a row for everyone but for those who are Friends I am getting 2 rows for them - one to say they are a Friend and one to say NULL

Does any of this make sense?

Query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       cl.ClientID, 
       cl.dcFirstName, 
       (SELECT  Dwh.DimClientTypes.dctName
        WHERE   (Dwh.DimClientTypes.dctGuid IN ('52CD80A6-D4D7-4FD3-8AE8-644A40FEC108'))
       ) AS Friend
FROM   Dwh.DimClientTypeDetails 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimClientTypes ON Dwh.DimClientTypeDetails.dctdTypeGuid = Dwh.DimClientTypes.dctGuid 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Dwh.DimClients AS cl ON Dwh.DimClientTypeDetails.dctdClientGuid = cl.dcClientGUID
```

I'm really not sure the best way of approaching it so any help/advice would be very gratefully received.

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Your subquery has no `FROM` clause.  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for a pivot with strings, and you could write it using the `pivot` or `apply` but this seems simpler.

```
select 
    Id      = cl.ClientId
  , Name    = cl.dcFirstName
  , Friend  = max(case when ct.dctName = 'Friend'  then ct.dctName else null end)
  , Enemy   = max(case when ct.dctName = 'Enemy'   then ct.dctName else null end)
  , Alien   = max(case when ct.dctName = 'Alien'   then ct.dctName else null end)
  , Monster = max(case when ct.dctName = 'Monster' then ct.dctName else null end)
  from Dwh.DimClients as cl
    left join Dwh.DimClientTypeDetails ctd on ctd.dctdClientGuid = cl.dcClientguid
    left join Dwh.DimClientTypes ct        on ct.dctGuid         = ctd.dctdTypeGuid
  group by cl.ClientId, cl.dcFirstName
```

For a pivot version, this is a good example: http://rextester.com/XDACE35377

```
create table #t (Id int not null, Name varchar(32)  not null, ClientType varchar(32) null)
insert into #t values 
 (35, 'John', 'Friend')
,(35, 'John', 'Monster')
,(42, 'Eric', null);
select
    Id
  , Name
  , pvt.Friend
  , pvt.Enemy
  , pvt.Alien
  , pvt.Monster
  from #t 
    pivot (max(ClientType) for ClientType in ([Friend],[Enemy],[Alien],[Monster])) pvt
```

This pivot could be done on your schema with something like this:

```
with c as (
  select 
      Id          = cl.ClientId
    , Name        = cl.dcFirstName
    , ClientType  = ct.dctName
    from Dwh.DimClients as cl
      left join Dwh.DimClientTypeDetails ctd on ctd.dctdClientGuid = cl.dcClientguid
      left join Dwh.DimClientTypes ct        on ct.dctGuid         = ctd.dctdTypeGuid
)
select
    Id
  , Name
  , pvt.Friend
  , pvt.Enemy
  , pvt.Alien
  , pvt.Monster
  from c 
    pivot (max(ClientType) for ClientType in ([Friend],[Enemy],[Alien],[Monster])) pvt
```